# How to add an icon to a MenuFlyout in UWP?

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to add an icon to a menuflyoutitem, I'd like that my menu looks similar to this one:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<AppBarButton.Flyout>
    <MenuFlyout>
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="SMS">
            <MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem">
                    <StackPanel Margin="12,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <SymbolIcon Margin="0,0,12,0" Symbol="Comment" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
        </MenuFlyoutItem>
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Email">
            <MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem">
                    <StackPanel Margin="12,10,0,10" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <SymbolIcon Margin="0,0,12,0" Symbol="MailForward" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
        </MenuFlyoutItem>
    </MenuFlyout>
</AppBarButton.Flyout>
```

I've been struggling and I cannot find a normal tutorial about it, does anybody know I should change? Because when I add the icon all the behaviour of the Menu is lost for example it doesn't change the color again when I'm over the menu. Thanks.

Comment: You havent included visual states inside ControlTemplate  of MenuFlyoutItem. So color is not changing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the behaviour of the Menu is lost because you are using your custom `MenuFlyoutItem` template and in your template, you didn't deal with different visual states.

By default, `MenuFlyoutItem` has 8 visual states which are **Normal**, **PointerOver**, **Pressed**, **Disabled**, **Unchecked**, **Checked**, **DefaultPadding**, and **NarrowPadding**. For more info, please check [MenuFlyoutItem styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt299138.aspx).

When you are over the menu, it triggers `PointerOver` state:

```
<VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock" />
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

And in this state, it changes the background and the TextBlock's foreground. However in your custom template, you didn't have any `VisualState`, so it didn't change the color.

To fix this issue, you can add visual states for each of your custom template.

Or you can create a custom style based on the default styles and templates and use [`Tag` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.tag.aspx) to set the `SymbolIcon` like:

```
<Style x:Key="MyMenuFlyoutItem" TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutItemThemePadding}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem">
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Backgroun
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Backgroun
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}" 
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckPlaceholderStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="NoPlaceholder" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="CheckPlaceholder">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutItemPlaceholderThemeThickness}
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PaddingSizeStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="DefaultPadding" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="NarrowPadding">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Padding">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutItemThemePaddingNarrow}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <SymbolIcon Margin="0,0,12,0" Symbol="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                   Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                   Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                                   TextTrimming="Clip" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And then, use this style in your `MenuFlyoutItem`:

```
<AppBarButton.Flyout>
    <MenuFlyout>
        <MenuFlyoutItem Style="{StaticResource MyMenuFlyoutItem}" Tag="Comment" Text="SMS" />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Style="{StaticResource MyMenuFlyoutItem}" Tag="MailForward" Text="Email" />
    </MenuFlyout>
</AppBarButton.Flyout>
```

The style I've used is just for example, you may need to edit it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to `Windows 10 Creators Update (introduced v10.0.15063.0)` `MenuFlyoutItem` now have a property `Icon`.

From [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/menus) :

```
<MenuFlyout>
    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Share" >
        <MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
            <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE72D;" />
        </MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
    </MenuFlyoutItem>
</MenuFlyout>
```

For more information be sure to check : [MenuFlyoutItem documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MenuFlyoutItem)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the info!

Comment: Somehow it won't show the icon in my code, it's exactly like yours. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can check your windows sdk version and if the Glyph you are using is existing : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/uwp/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font.

Answer (score 2):

MenuFlyoutIconGlyphIcon

```
 public class MenuFlyoutIconGlyph : MenuFlyoutItem
{
    public string GlyphIcon
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(GlyphIconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GlyphIconProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty GlyphIconProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("GlyphIcon", typeof(string), typeof(MenuFlyoutIconGlyph), new PropertyMetadata("uE10C"));
}
```

Style

```
 <!--With glyph icon-->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuFlyoutItemControlTemplate2" TargetType="controlEx:MenuFlyoutIconGlyph">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckPlaceholderStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="NoPlaceholder"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="CheckPlaceholder">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutItemPlaceholderThemeThickness}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PaddingSizeStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="DefaultPadding"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="NarrowPadding">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Padding" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutItemThemePaddingNarrow}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <StackPanel Margin="12,5,5,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <FontIcon Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"                         
                       HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                       Margin="0,0,12,0" Glyph="{TemplateBinding GlyphIcon}" 
                       VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            <TextBlock  x:Name="TextBlock" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                        Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" TextTrimming="Clip" 
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
<Style x:Key="MenuFlyoutItemStyleIconGlyph" TargetType="controlEx:MenuFlyoutIconGlyph" >
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutItemThemePadding}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MenuFlyoutItemControlTemplate2}">
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Sample

```
<Grid x:Name="grid">
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <MenuFlyout MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle="{StaticResource MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle}">
            <controlEx:MenuFlyoutIconGlyph Style="{StaticResource MenuFlyoutItemStyleIconGlyph}" Text="Share" GlyphIcon="&#xE122;"></controlEx:MenuFlyoutIconGlyph>
        </MenuFlyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the visul states for mouse hover. Here is the complete `ControlTemplate` of `MenuFlyoutItem` which is taken from this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299138.aspx)

```
<MenuFlyoutItem Text="SMS">
    <MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem">
            <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckPlaceholderStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="NoPlaceholder" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="CheckPlaceholder">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutItemPlaceholderThemeThickness}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PaddingSizeStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="DefaultPadding" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="NarrowPadding">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Padding">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutItemThemePaddingNarrow}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <StackPanel  Margin="12,10,0,10" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <SymbolIcon Margin="0,0,12,0" Symbol="MailForward" />
                    <TextBlock
                        x:Name="TextBlock"
                        Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                        TextTrimming="Clip"
                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
</MenuFlyoutItem>
```